# Check if values in one column are not unique based on values in other column

Tags: mysql, sql

**[DB-Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=4e22e734e144424fbb09d208e169deab)**

```
CREATE TABLE logistics (
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    campaign VARCHAR(255),
    process_status VARCHAR(255),
    delivery_type VARCHAR(255),
    quantity INT
);

INSERT INTO logistics
(campaign, process_status, delivery_type, quantity
)
VALUES 
("C001", "offer", "fedex", "500"),
("C001", "offer", "fedex", "200"),
("C001", "order", "ubs", "400"),
("C001", "shipped", "ubs", "100"),

("C002", "offer", "fedex", "800"),
("C002", "offer", "fedex", "100"),
("C002", "order", "fedex", "650"),
("C002", "shipped", "fedex", "250"),

("C003", "offer", "fedex", "730"),
("C003", "order", "fedex", "620"),
("C003", "shipped", "dhl", "530"),

("C004", "order", "fedex", "200"),
("C004", "shipped", "fedex", "130"),

("C005", "order", "fedex", "900"),
("C005", "shipped", "ubs", "475"),

("C006", "order", "fedex", "635");
```

**Expected Result**

```
campaign      process_status       delivery_type      quantity
C001          offer                fedex              700
C001          order                ubs                400
C001          shipped              ubs                100
C003          offer                fedex              730
C003          order                fedex              620        
C003          shipped              dhl                530
C005          offer                fedex              900
C005          shipped              ubs                475
```

---

In the above table I have different `campaigns`, their `process_status` and `delivery_type`. 
Now, I want to extract all `campaigns` which switch their `delivery_type` between different `process_status`.

Therefore, I am looking for a query that does something like this:

```
SELECT
campaign,
process_status,
delivery_type,
quantity
FROM logistics
WHERE delivery_type differes in different process_status
```

I have no clue how the `WHERE` condition must look to achieve the expected result. 
Do you have any idea?

Comment: nicely explained question and thumbs up for the DB fiddle and DDL and DML within the question

Comment: I think it may take time to reopen. You can check this [DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=71210526c689a8c98798b6590baaf8bf) for the answer. I will post it when it is reopened. @Michi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the below query.

```
SELECT 
campaign, process_status, delivery_type, sum(quantity) as quantity
FROM logistics
WHERE campaign IN (
    SELECT
    campaign
    FROM logistics
    GROUP BY campaign
    HAVING max(delivery_type)!=min(delivery_type)
)
GROUP BY campaign, process_status, delivery_type
```

[***Check Demo Here***](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=71210526c689a8c98798b6590baaf8bf)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This will give you all campaigns where delivery type different in different process states:

```
SELECT (campaign),count(1) AS cnt
FROM logistics
GROUP BY campaign,
         delivery_type
HAVING cnt>1;
```

You can add distinct if you want unique campaign values:

```
SELECT distinct(campaign),
       count(1) AS cnt
FROM logistics
GROUP BY campaign,
         delivery_type
HAVING cnt>1;
```

Answer (score 0):

**[DB-Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=7378bcf652ab2b69f92be4ca7a405964)**

```
/* Match all values to campaigns that fullfill condition */
SELECT
l2.campaign,
l2.process_status,
l2.delivery_type,
SUM(l2.quantity)
from logistics l2
JOIN

  /* Get campaigns that fullfill condition */
   (SELECT
   t1.campaign,
   t1.process_status,
   t1.delivery_type,
   t1.count_process_status,
   t1.count_delivery_status
   FROM

     /* Count process_status and delivery_status */
     (SELECT
     l.campaign,
     l.process_status,
     l.delivery_type,
     COUNT(DISTINCT l.process_status) as count_process_status,
     COUNT(DISTINCT l.delivery_type) as count_delivery_status,
     SUM(l.quantity)
     FROM logistics l
     GROUP BY 1) t1

    WHERE count_delivery_status > 1) t2 ON l2.campaign = t2.campaign

GROUP BY 1,2,3;
```